# How to speed up the time required to run the solution in vS2017?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

I am working on .Net project. I am using VS2017 as IDE. Whenever I click on Docker compose It will take minimum 4 to 5 minutes to hit the break point. Whenever I start, Nuget packages will start loading. I have attached screen shot below.

[image]

Below is my make file.

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=local
IPM_POSTGRES_ADDRESS=localhost
IPM_POSTGRES_PORT=5432
IPM_POSTGRES_USERNAME=kmart
IPM_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kmart
NUGET_PATH=~/.nuget
AVRO_PATH=~/.dotnet/tools
INSTALL_AVRO=0

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    NUGET_PATH=${USERPROFILE}\.nuget
    AVRO_PATH=${USERPROFILE}\.dotnet\tools

    ifeq (, $(shell where ${AVRO_PATH}:avrogen))
        INSTALL_AVRO=1
    endif
else
    ifeq (, $(shell which ${AVRO_PATH}/avrogen))
        INSTALL_AVRO=1
    endif
endif

.PHONY: restore restore-src restore-tests package test verify-appsettings test-in-docker test-watch start migration-add migration-remove migration-run migration-ignore-stylecop migration-create-template migration-remove-template

restore: restore-src restore-tests
restore-src:
    dotnet restore ReplenishmentService
restore-tests:
    dotnet restore ReplenishmentServiceTests

test-single:
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=test dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~${TEST_NAME}"

test-unit-only: generate-avro
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && dotnet test --filter Category!=Integration

test-watch-single:
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=test dotnet watch test --filter "FullyQualifiedName=${TEST_NAME}"
test-watch:
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=test dotnet watch test --filter Category!=Integration
test:
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose down
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose build
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose up -d
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose run dotnet-test /app/runtests.sh
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose down

validate-schema:
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose build dotnet-test
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose run --no-deps dotnet-test /app/validateSchema.sh

verify-appsettings:
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose run verify-appsettings

test-rerun-in-docker:
    cd ReplenishmentServiceTests && docker-compose run dotnet-test /app/runtests.sh

clean-docker:
    docker rmi -f replenishmentservice

build-docker: package
    docker-compose build replenishmentservice

build-image: build-docker

prune-docker-images:
    docker images -q -f dangling=true | xargs docker rmi

clean:
    rm -rf ReplenishmentService/out
    rm -rf ReplenishmentService/bin
    rm -rf ReplenishmentServiceTests/bin
    rm -rf ReplenishmentService/obj
    rm -rf ReplenishmentService/Models/IPM

initialise-local-databases: initialise-local-db2 initialise-local-postgres
    docker-compose up --detach replenishmentservice && \
    docker-compose exec replenishmentservice bash -c "until (curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail 'http://localhost:5000/api/status'); do sleep 5; done" && \
    docker-compose exec replenishmentservice bash -c "curl -id '' http://localhost:5000/api/stores/refresh" && \
    docker-compose down

reload-stores-cache:
    docker exec replenishmentservice bash -c "curl -id '' http://localhost:5000/api/stores/refresh"

initialise-local-databases-vb:
    docker exec replenishmentservice bash -c "until (curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail 'http://localhost:5000/api/status'); do sleep 5; done" && \
    docker cp scripts/pg/import_data.sql replenishment-postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import_data.sql && \
    docker exec replenishment-postgres psql kmart kmart -f /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import_data.sql && \
    docker exec replenishmentservice bash -c "curl --silent -id '' http://localhost:5000/api/stores/refresh"

initialise-local-postgres: migration-dump-schema
    docker-compose build replenishment-postgres

initialise-local-db2: purge-local-databases
    docker-compose build db2

purge-local-databases:
    docker-compose down --volumes

install-avro:
ifeq (1,$(INSTALL_AVRO))
    dotnet tool install --global Confluent.Apache.Avro.AvroGen
endif

AVRO_OUTDIR = ReplenishmentService/Models/IPM/ReplenishmentService
AVRO_OUTFILES = $(AVRO_OUTDIR)/ProductRangeEvent.cs $(AVRO_OUTDIR)/TimephaseUpdateEvent.cs

generate-avro: install-avro $(AVRO_OUTFILES)

$(AVRO_OUTDIR)/%.cs: ReplenishmentService/Models/%.avsc
    ${AVRO_PATH}/avrogen -s $< ReplenishmentService/Models

package: clean generate-avro
    cd ReplenishmentService && dotnet publish -c Release -o out

start: package build-docker stop
    docker-compose up

stop:
    docker-compose kill && docker-compose down

rebuild: package clean-docker build-docker
    docker-compose rm -f --stop replenishmentservice && docker-compose up --detach replenishmentservice

migration-remove-down:
    python scripts/removeDownMigrations.py ReplenishmentService/Migrations/*

migration-create-template:
    cd ReplenishmentService && dotnet ef migrations add --startup-project ReplenishmentService.csproj --context ReplenishmentParameterContext ${MIGRATION_NAME}
migration-remove-template:
    cd ReplenishmentService && dotnet ef migrations remove --startup-project ReplenishmentService.csproj --context ReplenishmentParameterContext

migration-add: migration-create-template
migration-remove: migration-remove-template migration-ignore-stylecop
migration-run:
    cd ReplenishmentService && ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=local IPM_POSTGRES_ADDRESS=localhost IPM_POSTGRES_PORT=5432 IPM_POSTGRES_USERNAME=kmart IPM_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kmart dotnet ef database update --startup-project ReplenishmentService.csproj --context ReplenishmentParameterContext --verbose

migration-scaffold:
    cd ReplenishmentService && dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold --startup-project ReplenishmentService.csproj --context ReplenishmentParameterContext --connection-string "

migration-dump-schema: package
    cd ReplenishmentService && dotnet ef migrations script --context ReplenishmentParameterContext > ../replenishment_data/scripts/1.ipmSchema.sql
```

May I know why this is taking four to five minutes and Is there any other way to decrease this time? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.